# maven release:prepare not honoring system properties

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a rest client implementation. As it is a client, an integration test with real credentials is in order. However, I don't want to check those in as part of the properties of the source code especially because it will be checked into github.

I am using `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` to load properties and and inject them into my beans. One of the properties I can set is

```
  <property name="systemPropertiesMode">
        <!-- this configuration is for security and forces these to be passed on commandline since they are dummy values in config-->
        <util:constant
                static-field="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    </property>
```

Which allows me to supply those properties on the commandline at release time for I can successfully get a release version out there.

```
mvn clean install -Dapp.username=foo -Dapp.password=bar
```

runs without a hitch. Tests succeed.

```
mvn clean release:prepare release:perform -Dapp.username=foo -Dapp.password=bar
```

Fails because the substitution isn't happening (my logs are clear on that).

I have tried:

```
mvn clean release:prepare release:perform -Darguments="-Dapp.username=foo -Dapp.password=bar"
```

and that doesn't work.

I have also tried adding a profile to my settings.xml for release:

```
<profile>
    <id>release</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <app.username>foo</app.username>
        <app.password>bar</app.password>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

That also fails.

I can't check in these credentials but I need to be able to have them for release and legitimate test. The properties in the file are dummy values and commented so the next time someone comes along they know what needs to be done.

Is there another way to approach this problem or am I simply not doing this approach right

Comment: Have you tried: mvn -Dapp.username=foo -Dapp.password=bar clean release:prepare release:perform -Darguments="-Dapp.username=foo -Dapp.password=bar"

Comment: I have tried them both independently. in > release:prepare it ignores the -D option. The nest -D is supposed to be passed to the forked process